# Filling missing data in pandas dataframe on the basis of a value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on filling missing values in a pandas dataframe that I have. The simplest case would be to use *df.fillna()* on the entire column with missing values. This works, but I would like to extend this by adding a condition.

Namely, I calculate the median based on the category and if a missing value has Label = 'A' then it is filled with the median of all values that have Label = 'A'

Likewise, if a value has Label = 'B', then it is filled with the median of all values that have Label = 'B'

Below is workable code.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[20,'A'],[24,'B'],[23,'A'],[22,'B'],[np.nan,'A'],[24,'B'],[np.nan,'B']],columns=['Value','Label'])

A_median = np.nanmedian(df[df['Label']=='A']['Value'])
B_median = np.nanmedian(df[df['Label']=='B']['Value'])
```

Currently the dataframe is:

```
    Value   Label
0   20.0    A
1   24.0    B
2   23.0    A
3   22.0    B
4   NaN     A
5   24.0    B
6   NaN     B
```

The desired output is:

```
    Value   Label
0   20.0    A
1   24.0    B
2   23.0    A
3   22.0    B
4   21.5    A
5   24.0    B
6   24.0    B
```

I tried the following but it causes all other values to be NaN:

```
df['Value'] = df[df['Label'] == 'A']['Value'].fillna(A_median)
```

Thank you in advance for your help! Please let me know if you need further information :)

Edit: I know similar questions have been asked but I mainly am trying to understand how to set the value without causing the other category to be null.

Comment: use `df['Value'].fillna(df.groupby('Label')['Value'].transform('mean'),inplace=True)`

Comment: Use `df['Value'] = df['Value'].fillna(df.groupby('Label')['Value'].transform('median'))`

Comment: Thank you guys. I searched for a while and never found that question but it solves the issue perfectly.